# How to disable routing in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes, angular2-routing

I have a generic menu bar component consist of home, overview and analyzer.  What i need is while clicking on the overview, the default view should be retained(ie the home view) but a modal popup should open over the home view.

Is there is any solution to do this?

[generic menu component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqmdb.png)

Comment: So you want a menu with 2 link(home, analyzer - got to /home , /analyzer) and one button(overview- this will open popup) ?!

Comment: no, actually 3 of them are router links. what i need is while clicking overview(that is also a link) a popup should fire without changing the current route.

Comment: can you add your html and ts file ? BTW I don't understand why you say the popup click is an link since you are not changing route. HTML5 defines 'a' link as a router navigation and a 'button' as an action. But if u insists of keeping the routerLink than you can try to store param in TS than insert in your routerLink and add a (click) function